# Sequence of primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is a previous year question and I have no idea how to start.

Let $p_1<p_2<....<p_{31}$ be prime numbers such that $30$ divides $\sum_{i=1}^{31}p_i^4$.

Prove that $p_1=2, ~p_2=3 , ~p_3=5$?

Any hints please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\;30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\,$ ... and, of course, unique prime decomposition for integers.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for the insight. Now it looks very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this problem appears to be Fermat's Little Theorem.  If this isn't enough, hover your mouse over the text below.

> By Fermat's Little Theorem, if $p_i\ne5,p_i^4\equiv1\pmod 5$.  If $5$ is not one of the primes, your sum is congruent to $1\pmod5$ and is therefore not divisible by $5$ or $30$.  Therefore, one of the primes must be $5$.  The same argument works for $2$ and $3$.